Tree: Preorder Transversal
import java.util.*;

class Node {
    String id;
    int point;
    List<Node> children;
    Node parent;

    Node(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.point = 0;
        this.children = new ArrayList<>();
        this.parent = null;
    }
}

class Solution {
    private static Map<String, Node> nodeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static Node buildTree(String rootId, List<String[]> queries) {
        Node root = new Node(rootId);
        nodeMap.put(rootId, root);
        
        for (String[] query : queries) {
            String recruiterId = query[0];
            String recruitId = query[1];
            
            Node recruiterNode = nodeMap.getOrDefault(recruiterId, new Node(recruiterId));
            Node recruitNode = nodeMap.getOrDefault(recruitId, new Node(recruitId));
            
            recruiterNode.children.add(recruitNode);
            recruitNode.parent = recruiterNode;
            
            updateAncestors(recruiterNode, 1);
            
            nodeMap.put(recruiterId, recruiterNode);
            nodeMap.put(recruitId, recruitNode);
        }
        
        return root;
    }

    private static void updateAncestors(Node node, int point) {
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.parent != null && !node.parent.children.isEmpty()) {
                boolean hasGrandChildren = false;
                boolean hasChildren = false;
                
                for (Node child : node.children) {
                    if (hasGrandChildren(child)) {
                        hasGrandChildren = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
                if (!node.children.isEmpty()) {
                    hasChildren = true;
                }
                
                if (hasGrandChildren) {
                    node.point += 3;
                } else if (hasChildren) {
                    node.point += 2;
                } else {
                    node.point += 1;
                }
            } else {
                node.point += 1;
            }
            node = node.parent;
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasGrandChildren(Node node) {
        if (node.children.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        
        for (Node child : node.children) {
            if (!child.children.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            if (hasGrandChildren(child)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    public static void preorderTraversal(Node root) {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(root);
        
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            Node current = stack.pop();
            System.out.println(current.id + " " + current.point);
            
            for (int i = current.children.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                stack.push(current.children.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yourId = scanner.nextLine();
        int T = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        List<String[]> queries = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            String[] query = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            queries.add(query);
        }
        
        Node root = buildTree(yourId, queries);
        preorderTraversal(root);
    }
}

how to make sure that the parent or ancestor gets a 1 point bonus if the child has children?
Example:
Input
011 (root)
10 (amount of data)
011 012
011 013
011 014
014 023
014 022
014 033
011 015
015 077
015 088
088 039

Output
011 14
012 0
013 0
014 6
023 0
022 0
033 0
015 5
077 0
088 2
039 0

If the parent node has children it will get 2 points/children, if the child node has children then the parent/ancestor node will get 1 bonus point. (get 1 point bonus/grandchild)
#Node 011 has 14 points because it has children: node 012, 013, 014, and 015. but node 014 (3 child), 015 (2 child) has children too and node 088 have children so node 011 gets 1 bonus point/grandchild (2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1).
This is my output](https://i.sstatic.net/gw2qp2nI.png)

Please don't post images of text. Also, you don't seem to have asked a question.

I asked the question about how parents can get bonus points because I don't know how @tgdavies

Try a much smaller example, and run your code under the debugger so that you can see what it's doing. Then ask a specific question if there's some aspect of its behaviour that you don't understand.

can you post image of tree with its default values? its difficult to understand in this way

Please explain why node 014 gets 6 points.

Because node 014 have child so node 014 get 2 points/child (023, 022, 033). @trincot

The rules are not clear to me. If a node gets two points for each child, then please mention that (currently you say that if a node has children it gets 2 points). Still then I don't get why the root gets 14 points. I count that it has 4 children (2x4 = 8), and gets bonus points for the fact that nodes 014, 015 and 088 have children (3 bonus), which totals to 11, not 14. How do you get 14?

node 014 have 3 children so node 011 get 3 points bonus, 015 have 2 children, and 088 have 1 children so total points bonus = 6. @trincot

So it is a bonus point per child? Please, can you edit your question, because there you say the bonus is given because of having children, but that is not the same.

okay i'll edit @trincot

What you explain as rule for gathering points comes down to the following logic:
A node gets a point for every descendant it has, plus a point for every child it has. As a child is both a descendant and child, a child node will contribute 2 points this way.
In updateAncestors you overcomplicate things. The reason it gets so complicated is that this function is called when the tree is not yet completely built.
I would suggest to first build the whole tree, and then you can apply a simple logic: for every node do this:

Add to its points the number of children it has
Traverse upward the tree and add a bonus of 1 to every node on the path to the root.

That's it.
Here is how your buildTree could take care of that:
    public static Node buildTree(String rootId, List<String[]> queries) {
        Node root = new Node(rootId);
        nodeMap.put(rootId, root);

        for (String[] query : queries) {
            String recruiterId = query[0];
            String recruitId = query[1];

            Node recruiterNode = nodeMap.getOrDefault(recruiterId, new Node(recruiterId));
            Node recruitNode = nodeMap.getOrDefault(recruitId, new Node(recruitId));

            recruiterNode.children.add(recruitNode);
            recruitNode.parent = recruiterNode;

            // Don't calculate points yet. First finish building the tree.

            nodeMap.put(recruiterId, recruiterNode);
            nodeMap.put(recruitId, recruitNode);
        }
        // Now distribute the points:
        for (Node recruiterNode : nodeMap.values()) {
            // 1 point per direct child
            recruiterNode.point += recruiterNode.children.size(); 
            // Grant a bonus point to every ancestor:
            Node ancestor = recruiterNode.parent;
            while (ancestor != null) {
                // 1 point as this is an ancestor of recruiterNode
                ancestor.point += 1; 
                ancestor = ancestor.parent;
            }
        }
        return root;
    }


Thanks for help me and and gave me advice
